# Changing owner of bounty rewards

Tags: feature-request, bounty

A few seconds ago I gave bounty to wrong answer because of my distractibility . How can I change it? I think we should be able to change owner of bounty's in first 5 minutes after giving bounty.

**Question** : [Change Fieldset Fields' required parameter dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461683/change-fieldset-fields-required-parameter-dynamically/34510179#34510179)

Comment: I can start a new one and award it to the right guy if you want (and if I remember to do it when it expires)

Comment: so you will start new bounty for me, right? @Pekka웃

Comment: Yeah, done. Will award it when I can, in 24 hours I think

Comment: Can I give it back?

Comment: @AlexP oh, you don't want it? What a shame, all for nothing :) I guess you can flag for moderator attention and ask them to remove it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 ha, thought it was given to me incorrectly :-) Thanks

Comment: Pekka , thank you for your help and @AlexP thank you also for your answer. You deserved it :)